# How to parse a string value out of a RadGrid cell for use in RadGrid PreRender event?

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgvBoards" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GroupPanelPosition="Top" 
                            OnPreRender="rgvBoards_PreRender" DataSourceID="odsBoard">
                            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BoardID" DataSourceID="odsBoard" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>                                                                           
                                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="InActivate" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../images/cancelDelete.gif" 
                                        CommandName="InActivate" Display="True">
                                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="Activate" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../images/greenCheck.png"
                                        CommandName="InActivate" Display="True">
                                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>                                            
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BoardStatus" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="Status" 
                                        UniqueName="BoardStatus">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" PageSizes="10;20;30;999" />
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The goal is that only one button will be displayed per row.  So that when the status is marked active ("A") the "InActivate" button will display.

I have been trying to use the preRender event to make this happen.  I know my preRender event is being read and has an affect on the grid because without applying logic to read the BoardStatus column I can control which buttons display:

```
    Protected Sub rgvBoards_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            rgvBoards.MasterTableView.GetColumn("InActivate").Display = False
            rgvBoards.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Activate").Display = False
    End Sub
```

I have tried quite a few of the suggestions from the telerik forums and their documentation such as:

```
    Protected Sub rgvBoards_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim dataItem As GridDataItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        Dim itemValue As String = dataItem("BoardStatus").Text

        If itemValue.Equals("A") Then
            rgvBoards.MasterTableView.GetColumn("InActivate").Display = False
        ElseIf itemValue.Equals("I") Then
            rgvBoards.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Activate").Display = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

which produces the problem that 'item' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'.

What is the proper way to read a RadGrid cell and put it in a string variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is using the 'OnNeedDataSource' event.
HTML:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgvBoards" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GroupPanelPosition="Top" 
                             OnNeedDataSource="rgvBoards_NeedDataSource" DataSourceID="odsBoard">
                            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BoardID" DataSourceID="odsBoard" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>                                    
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ImageButtonColumn">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/cancelDelete.gif"
                                            CommandName="InActivate" Visible='<%# Eval("BoardStatus").Equals("A")%>'
                                            AlternateText="InActivate" />

                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/greenCheck.png"
                                            CommandName="Activate" Visible='<%# Eval("BoardStatus").Equals("I")%>'
                                            AlternateText="Activate" />

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BoardStatus" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="Status" 
                                        UniqueName="BoardStatus" DataType="System.String">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" PageSizes="10;20;30;999" />
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

along with this on the back end (VB):

```
Protected Sub rgvBoards_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs)
        rgvBoards.DataSource = GetGridSource()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetGridSource() As DataTable
        Dim dataTable As New DataTable()

        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = Type.[GetType]("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "BoardStatus"
        dataTable.Columns.Add(column)

        Dim PrimaryKeyColumns As DataColumn() = New DataColumn(0) {}
        PrimaryKeyColumns(0) = dataTable.Columns("BoardID")
        dataTable.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns

        Return dataTable
    End Function
```

Has allowed me to have the RadGrid render the proper image button using the board status as the deciding factor.

Source:  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-advanced-data-binding.html